# If you roll four dice what is the probability of getting at least two sixes?

Tags: probability, dice

First of all, I know there are a lot of these and similar questions already online but I am trying to solve this on my own and I need you to tell me what I am doing wrong. So, in class we solved problem like this: 
\begin{align*}
\text{Probability} & = \frac{\text{positive events}}{\text{all possible events}}\\
           & = \frac{\binom{4}{2} \cdot 5^2 + \binom{4}{3} \cdot 5 + 1}{6^4}
\end{align*}

My question is why cannot we solve it like this?

$$\frac{\binom{4}{2} \cdot 6^2}{6^4}$$

where $\binom{4}{2}$ is the number of ways of obtaining six in two of the four trials and where $6^2$ are two remaining dice which can be any number but it does not matter which because we already have two six from choosing $2$ from $4$?

Comment: Because you will count $(6,6,6,1)$ more than one time. First as $(6,6,\cdot, \cdot)$ then as $(\cdot, 6 ,6 , \cdot)$ and finally as $(6 , \cdot , 6 \cdot )$.

Comment: The reason is you would be over counting redundant results.  One of the favored results will be 3 sixes. You have accounted for that three times.

Comment: WElcome to MSE, quicks tips for you: 1. This site uses [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference) to write in a  good mathematical form. 2. It is mandatory to add your own attempts on solving the problem and where you got stuck , so that others can help you.  3. Please have a look on [How to ask a good question](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How many ways are there to roll 4 sixes?

Is it: choose 2 of the 4 to be sixes and *it doesn't matter about the other 2* because they are also sixes?   That is $\binom{4}{2}$, which is $6$ .

Or is it: $1$ ?

Therein lies the reason why.  Your technique would over count such redundant results.